# Cannot get AWS Lambda to PutObject to S3 in same account no matter what

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to write a lambda to run FFMPEG in an AWS lambda.  I have done this before at another workplace so I know that it is possible.

The log shows that I make a Temporary URL to read the file in, it processes with FFMPEG, I pipe the output to a byte[] which is showing data in it, and then I try to do an S3 PutObjectRequest, which always fails with this message:

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

The S3 client is the same credentials that I use automated all the time to upload files to S3 from different servers at different locations of our company.  I have tried a couple different IAMs to no effect.

I am not trying to do any sort of signature whatsoever. I am simply doing this:

```
        var putRequest = new PutObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = m.Groups["bucket"].Value,
            Key = m.Groups["key"].Value,
            InputStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data ?? "")),
            CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead,
            ContentType = MimeTypes.GetMimeType(Path.GetExtension(m.Groups["key"].Value)),
            DisablePayloadSigning = true,
        };
        putRequest.Headers.ContentLength = data.Length;
        _context.Logger.LogLine($"Saving file to bucket '{putRequest.BucketName}' and key '{putRequest.Key}' and content type '{putRequest.ContentType}' and content length {putRequest.Headers.ContentLength}");

        try
        {
            await _s3Client.PutObjectAsync(putRequest);
        }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception s3x)
        {
            _context.Logger.LogLine($"S3 Exception: {s3x.Message}");
        }
```

I have checked bucket and key and they are correct.  Data.length is greater than 0.  Content type is "audio/mpeg", which is correct for .mp3. The data is there to be written.

My lambda is running under AWSLambda_Full_Access with the following additional rights granted:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListStorageLensConfigurations",
            "s3:ListAccessPointsForObjectLambda",
            "s3:GetAccessPoint",
            "s3:PutAccountPublicAccessBlock",
            "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "s3:*",
            "s3:ListAccessPoints",
            "s3:ListJobs",
            "s3:PutStorageLensConfiguration",
            "s3:ListMultiRegionAccessPoints",
            "s3:CreateJob"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas what else I could be missing?  I have been stuck on this one problem for over 3 days now and have tried everything I can think of, so it must be something I'm not thinking of.

Thanks.

Comment: What are the values of `m.Groups["bucket"].Value` and `.Groups["key"].Value` exactly?

Comment: Using the same credentials, do something simpler like list the S3 bucket or download an S3 object. Does it work?

Comment: Why use creds in a Lambda function. You should use an IAM role that has permissions to invoke Amazon S3 operations.   I know interacting with Amazon S3 using a Lambda function written in Java has no issues.

Comment: maybe there's an explicit deny in the resource policy of your S3 bucket

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary {corpRedacted}radio and outputTest.mp3.

Comment: @jarmod I use the same S3Client credentials to create a generated temporary URL for the input file in the same bucket, which is read by FFMPEG.  Works just fine.

Comment: or maybe this setting is preventing you client library to properly sign the request DisablePayloadSigning = true, try set it to false

Comment: @AnisSmail Permissions overview Access Objects can be public.  All public access restrictions are Off.

Comment: @AnisSmail Also, I have tried both true and false for this setting.  I only tried it because of the error message.

Comment: @smac2020 I agree.  At first I had no creds in the Lambda function, just a profile selected in the C# AWS tools.  But that didn't work so I tried to be more explicit with something I know worked.  I also tried matching the credentials to the profile selected.

Comment: does the code work in local ?

Comment: @AnisSmail Difficult to test locally, since I need Windows to call the command line for Linux ffmpeg, which is impossible.  I mean, I guess as a test I could call Windows FFMPEG instead.

Comment: @AnisSmail It's the same when running it locally in a test case using    if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
            {
                filename = @"C:\AV\FFMpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe";
            }
to access my local Windows ffmpeg.

Comment: Try with a tmp file instead of a MemoryStream. It's strange that you encode it with  utf-8 as S3 expect to find an image. Also the data.Length won't be equal to the actual length of what's returned by Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes.

Comment: Did you manage ?